# Good list of weak cipher suites for Java

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I'm running a server that requires a blacklist of weak cipher suites.

So which of the following are weak?
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider

Comment: Supporting Elliptic Curve in Java is extremely difficult. RSA, Diffie-Hellman, and Triple-DES aren't "weak", they just aren't "the best".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you need to exclude the bad ones? Why not only include the good ones?

For starters, I'd follow the [NSA Suite B](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/programs/suiteb_cryptography/index.shtml) guidelines, specifically [RFC 5430](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5430.txt?number=5430)

Comment: @John Smith: agreeing with Kevin here. For anything related to security, disable everything by default and then whitelist what you want to allow. That's how good firewall are configured too: deny everything by default, "whitelist" authorized traffic.

Comment: Jetty uses a black list up until version 6.1.21 so I'm stuck for now lol

Comment: @John We get around that by overriding the SslSocketConnector#createFactory() method to provide a pre-configured SSLServerSocketFactory that will create sockets with the correct cipher suites enabled on them.

Comment: I know but I can't change that right now so it's all good. If I understand the RFC correctly the only two viable cipher suites supported by JAVA are: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Comment: You can get the default listing of enabled cipher suites from here.  Anything that is in there but not in RFC 5430 can be considered "weak" I suppose: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocketFactory.html#getDefaultCipherSuites%28%29

Comment: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider <-- Here is the list. Basically 2 cipher suites are considered strong.

Answer (score 4):

Versions [after 7.0.2](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1164) of Jetty now include a whitelist feature for cipher suites. Just add a section to your etc/jetty-ssl.xml like the following:

```
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
        <Arg><Ref id="sslContextFactory" /></Arg>
        <Set name="Port">8443</Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="AcceptQueueSize">100</Set>

        <!--you can enable cipher suites in the following section. -->
        <Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">
          <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
            <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
            <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
            <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>

            <Item>TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
            <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
          </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
```

Doing so will automatically blacklist any cipher suites that aren't listed in this section.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure Jetty is blacklist.

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/SSL+Cipher+Suites
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1164 <-- I'm using slightly older version lol

Anyways my issue is solved. Thanks