# IIS TLS Certificate - Chrome says we are using "obsolete cryptography"

Tags: iis, ssl

We have installed a server certificate in IIS for a website. When browsing over HTTPS to the website and inspecting the icon using chrome, we get a message "Your connection ... is encrypted with obsolete cryptography".

How do I configure IIS so that Chrome stops displaying this message, also need to balance the need to support IE>=8.

[image]

[EDIT]: As per the screenshot, we can see that the encryption method used is "AES_256_CBC with SHA1 for message authentication". The question is how do we change this in IIS so that Chrome no longer complains about "Obselete Cryptography".

Answer (score 12):

The answer Steffen gave is incorrect (although the link he provided does provide the answer if you read further down). The reason Chrome gives the error regarding obsolete cryptography in this case is due to AES in CBC mode.

It has nothing to do with having a SHA-1 certificate.

**The TL;DR - ignore this error, it doesn't matter.**

If you really want to get rid of the error then you need to enable AES GCM instead. However this is easier said than done. I answered this in full on serverfault recently - see the second half of my answer here;

https://serverfault.com/questions/683697/change-key-exchange-mechanism-in-iis-8/683705#683705

Answer (score 4):

Since am new to SSL and certificates, I struggled with this too. Here's how we solved this issue. Note that in our case, we are working with an internal web application and use a self-signed certificate.

1. Using OpenSSL on Linux, create a private key:
   `openssl genrsa -out box.key 2048`
2. Then create and sign a certificate with the key (we set the expire date for a year out and 10 days):
   `openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 375 -key box.key -out box.crt`
3. Answer the questions (make sure the `Common Name` matches the web server's FQDN)
4. Configure your web server to use SSL using this key and certificate
5. Using Chrome on Windows, enter your web sites HTTPS URL
6. Click on the lock icon in the address bar, then select the `Certificate Information` link in the popup
7. Go to the `Details` tab, select the `Copy to File...` button to launch the `Certificate Export Wizard`
8. Using the wizard, select PKCS #7 as the export format, and save the certificate (i.e. `mykey.p7b`)
9. Install the certificate in the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` certificate store (use `certmgr.msc` or right click on the certificate and select `Install Certificate`
10. Close Chrome, logout and re-login to Windows (force the old site warning out of the cache)
11. Re-open Chrome and enter your web sites HTTPS URL
12. Admire your [shiny green lock](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-UHx65YMbUOE/VULCzqFiOII/AAAAAAAABlQ/T2u4US6t7Mk/s640/modern-cryptography-lock.png) icon with *modern cryptography*

Comment: The secret sauce is the number of bits in the `open genrsa` command and the use of the `-sha256` engine in the `openssl req` command

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/education/tls#TOC-Deprecation-of-TLS-Features-Algorithms-in-Chrome, which was the first hit when looking for this specific error message.

It is hard to know for sure without having a look at your certificate, but I guess the following description from the linked page will match your certificate:

> SHA-1 is deprecated in Chrome at the start of 2015.
>   Certificates expiring in 2016 will be marked as "secure, but with minor errors".
>   Certificates expiring in 2017 are later will be treated as "affirmatively insecure".

Comment: OK. How does one change the cryptography used by IIS from SHA-1 to something else that will be acceptable to Chrome?

Comment: The problem is not IIS but your certificate.  Contact your certificate vendor about the problem. But note that this solution here is only a guess based on your incomplete information.

Comment: Sorry Steffen that's just not true. RSA cryptography is used to exchange encryption keys for symmetric cryptography, and it's the symmetric cryptography that Chrome is complaining about. As per my screenshot, the symmetric cryptography uses "AES_256_CBC with SHA-1 for message authentication", this is the bit that chrome does not like and which we need to change in IIS. (This is the bit I was hoping someone would me with).

Comment: Cryptography is used on multiple places. It is not only used for key exchange and symmetric cryptography but also to validate the certificate chain. In this context (i.e. as a signature algorithm) SHA-1 is considered unsafe while in the context of symmetric cryptography (i.e. as a HMAC) SHA-1 is still considered safe. Thus the problem is the certificate and not the cipher.

Comment: This stuff was great to read! Out of curiosity, how did you get to solve this? Did the certificate vendor generate a new certificate for your website?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

1. Ensure latest Windows Updates have been installed
2. Download and run IIS Crypto (https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto)
3. Ensure that this Cipher is top of the list on the left hand side:

   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
4. Apply changes in IIS Crypto
5. Restart the server

Answer (score 0):

[In this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238135/good-list-of-weak-cipher-suites-for-java) there are a black and a white lists about ciphers. Maybe if you just use the white ones it would solve your problem. Look after the lists in the comments you will see that it has change a little since the answer was written.

It helped me a lot when I started to have this problem with Glassfish, I hope it helps you with IIS too.