# GF3 (JDK 6) how to config security protocol to remove obsolete cryptography

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, ssl, glassfish-3

In the company that I work we have a server GF 3.1.1 (JDK 6) with CAS which does the authentication of the users in another system. After the last update of Firefox (v. 39x) we are getting the follow information from the browser:

> mydomain.com  SSL received a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman key in
> Server Key Exchange handshake message.

And it is not possible to access the site without [this workaround](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/questions/1066238#answer-738971) or using another browser.
In chrome I can access normally but if I look at the connection properties it says:

> Your connection is encrypted with obsolete cryptography.
>
> The connection uses TLS 1.0.
>
> The connection is encrypted using
> AES_128_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication an DHE_RSA as the
> key exchange mechanism.

I can't configure all the browsers of our customers or say them only use chrome. Maybe in future chrome can do the same. So my solution is configure the server properly. The problem is that I don't know how can I do that.

I found in GF where I can do the configuration in Configurations > server-config > Network Config > Protocols > http-listner-2 > SSL

Then I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238135/good-list-of-weak-cipher-suites-for-java) a blacklist and a whitelist of some ciphers that are recommended to use. I tried to remove all in black and put all those in white. But I still have the issue. I think this list may be out of date.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: So what are you asking? For an up-to-date list of ciphers?

Comment: More or less. As I understood I have to update the version of TLS 1.0 to 1.1 or 1.2 better and use recommended ciphers (an up-to-date list). GF has a list of ciphers which I choose what I want to use, but I don't know what do when I have to set a cipher that is not listed there.

Comment: Indeed now also Chrome barfs on Glassfish. But see solution below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally. I found a solution. 
I search a lot and I could find a solution, so I tried to test one by one of the ciphers. So, to work ( I am not saying that is the right way). I had to do this:

At:

> Configurations > server-config > Network Config > Protocols > http-listner-2 > SSL

1. Add all the ciphers available
2. Remove all the Diffie-Hellman ciphers
3. Save

After that our application can be opened at any browser again. I hope it may help someone.

For admin:

> Configurations > server-config > Service HTTP > Listeners HTTP > admin-listner > SSL

1. Add all the ciphers available
2. Remove all the Diffie-Hellman ciphers
3. Save
4. Restart

**Edit:** Comparing with the [whitelist here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238135/good-list-of-weak-cipher-suites-for-java) the remaining ciphers that would be part of a new whitelist are:

**Whitelist**

1. TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
2. SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem as well with Chrome and the admin console. The way I got around it was to delete the current ssl certificate for the listener and recreate it using a specific set of ciphers with the --ssl3tlsciphers option. For me it was the admin-listener so first I deleted the current default certificate:

```
asadmin delete-ssl --type http-listener admin-listener
```

Then I recreated it using the following command:

```
asadmin create-ssl --type http-listener --certname s1as --ssl3tlsciphers SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5,SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV,SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5,SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA    admin-listener
```

I noticed that simply deleting the default certificate doesn't remove all references to it in the domain.xml file. I haven't been able to find the proper way to do this. I just used trial and error. Another method is to modify the domain.xml file where the ssl element for the listener is defined and add the attribute "ssl3-tls-ciphers":

```
<ssl ssl3-tls-ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5,SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV,SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5,SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA" classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl" cert-nickname="s1as"></ssl>
```

Both methods require a restart of glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Sertage, that worked!

However, it is also necessary to fix the Protocol for the admin port (usually 4848). (It should, of course, use HTTPS too!)

But, in GF 3.1.2.2, the Protocol 'admin-listener' appears to be kind of pointing to the Protocol 'sec-admin-listener', and that does not have a 'SSL' tab. Changing the SSL parameters the Protocol 'admin-listener' results in an error message, saying 'Could not apply changes. No Configuration found for configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.admin-listener.ssl'. Any suggestions on how to configure the admin port?

Comment: Is good to know that I could help someone. As, in our company, we only have access to the server by the internal network  the admin protocol is disabled. But you are right, it should be secure too. I will try to see if I can figure out something.

Comment: @PerLindberg First change another protocol along the lines described by Sertage. Then I think you can copy the change to the sec-admin-listener protocol by editing the domain.xml file. Copy the ssl3-tls-ciphers attribute from the ssl element in the protocol element you changed and add it to the ssl element in the sec-admin-listener protocol.  Be sure to backup your config directory.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just copy the XML attribute ssl3-tls-ciphers from <protocol name="http-listener-2"><ssl> to <protocol name="sec-admin-listener"><ssl>.